# Pager adapter in baseadapter of listview

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-pageradapter

I am using pageradapter in listview. every thing working fine but when i scroll the listview pager adapter reset and recreating the images which are in viewpager. please give me solution how to get out of this problem . i want to stop calling getview every time because of that pageradaoter reset ,'

Thanks

Comment: please put some relevant code here

Comment: PageAdapter in ListView - that sounds scary.

Comment: yes i know but .. need

Comment: We'll need to see your adapter code